The symbols in the C source code file are automatically replaced after I save(maybe)
When I opened the file in my editor, I found that # had been replaced with +ACM-, < with +ADw-, > with +AD4-, and "\n with +ACIAXA-n. I searched some keywords on the search engine, but got no results, so I came here for help.
This problem came up when I was writing a program that was generated from multiple source files, including one .h file and two  .c files. I remember when I referenced a function defined in one of the files and the compiler showed me (or "prompted") something containing "ACM,ADs" and I wondered what that was.
I tried to search for +ACM- and +ACM- on a search engine, to no avail.
I tried changing the encoding format of the file and nothing changed.
<--Add after the fact-->
This problem occurs when using Embarcad Dev-C++, which supports UTF-7 encoding.

Welcome to SO. What is your editor? What does "generated from multiple source files" mean? Do you autogenerate code? Did you run preprocessor over these files and look at the result? Do you just mean the program contains multiple compilation units? Also, what OS are you using?

Which compiler, and which editor? I have seen the odd peculiarity in MSVC 2022 where an individual #define can go invisible for no apparent reason. That is the line is in the file according to any other text editor but cannot be seen inside the IDE. I've never seen any file corruption like the OP describes. They look to me like some sort of escape sequence that I don't recognise (reminiscent of ancient modem commands).

Inerestingly, I found a few webpages that seem to be broken in the same way. here, here, here

It looks like UTF-7.

From How-to-ask: "Respond to feedback after posting - After you post, don't run away too fast—leave the question open in your browser for a bit to see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it."

It would really be interesting, how you got your files UTF-7 encoded...

This is indeed UTF-7 encoding.
E.g. +ACM- translates (by Base64) to the bit sequence:
  000000 000010 001100

which comes from the following (with two 0's appended to get a multiple of 6 bits for the base64 encoding):
  0000 0000 0010 0011

which again corresponds to U+0023, i.e. the character #.

Ah! The two appended bits were throwing me. I was interpreting it as U+008C  (PLU).
